# Custom notification layout: Bad notification posted from package Couldn't expand RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm getting that disgusting exception when trying to use some custom layout for my notifications. I've cropped the notification to image and 2 TextViews to ease solution finding, but it still won't work. All advices from similar questions didn't help (((

Here's the code from broadcast receiver:

```
public class ReminderOccurredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public ReminderOccurredReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PreferencesWrapper mPrefs = PreferencesWrapper.getWrapper(context);
        boolean uses12HourClock = mPrefs.getIfUse12HourClock();
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(mPrefs.getSoundUri());

        String serializedReminder = intent.getStringExtra("reminder");
        Reminder reminder = new Gson().fromJson(serializedReminder, Reminder.class);

        Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, EditReminderActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra("serializedReminder", serializedReminder);
        PendingIntent pEditIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, reminder.getDbId(), editIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
        notificationView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_message, reminder.getMessage());
        notificationView.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_time, reminder.getFormattedTZTime(uses12HourClock));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(reminder.getMessage())
            .setContent(notificationView)
            .setContentIntent(pEditIntent);
//            .setSound(soundUri)

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(reminder.getDbId(), builder.build());
    }
}
```

And here's a notification layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_height"
    android:padding="3dp"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/notif_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/notif_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notif_image"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/notif_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notif_image"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see - nothing complicated here. Where can a mistake be hidden?

Testing on Nexus4 @ 4.4.4

Comment: Did you ever solve this? You could post the exception log so we can take a look as to what's going on.

Comment: Yep, I managed to solve. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of crash was in fixed height of notification layout provided, as I remember. Only `match_parent` is available there. I bet it's even stated in the docs somewhere and I've simply overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed height of notification, is not the reason of crash, if you specified the value directly inside the layout, the notification works, but it's not a good android development practice.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    >
```

`wrap_content` also work here,`match_parent` is not the only solution available.

The issue come from `@dimen` define inside main Layout of RemoteViews.